# Is it possible to change inflation in openttd while it is running?

Tags: openttd

I do not want to restart the server, but I would like to stop inflation in the game. It is quite annoying that price are increasing. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not aware of anything related to server implementation (as I don't play the game in a regular basis), a quick search through the [OpenTTD wiki](http://wiki.openttd.org/Advanced_Settings/Economy#Inflation) shows a setting that disables inflation all together.

It can be found at Advanced Settings > Economy > Inflation.

Also to note that before OpenTTD 1.3.0 there was no option to disable inflation, as it was somehow merged with the [economy](http://wiki.openttd.org/Difficulty) status.

Answer (score 1):

This question has an answer applicable for single-player play, but not when running a headless openttd server.

**Configuration over SSH**

In order to change the setting on a running server, while SSHed into the box in the session or screen that is running the server, use the console command

```
set <setting> <value>
```

In your case, in particular: try:

```
set inflation false
```

Some settings may require you to restart the game. Restarting the server should not be ever necessary to change settings. In order to start a new game, use the command:

```
restart
```

**In-game configuration via rcon**

Normally, you must execute these commands on the server itself (e.g. by SSHing into it).
In order for this to work on a server where OpenTTD is running as a background process (you have for example forked it), you will have to have configured either an *rcon_password* or *admin_password*  beforehand. These can be found in the [network] section of the configuration file *openttd.cfg*. Example:

```
[network]
rcon_password = "8MuQooL$pl595"
```

With the rcon_password you can use the in-game console as a client by prefixing your commands like so: `rcon <rcon_password> "<command>"`; so the example becomes:

```
rcon 8MuQooL$pl595 "set inflation false"
```

**Programmable configuration**

If you would like to program these settings (e.g. so a moderator could change game settings via a web-interface) you can use the admin interface. How to do Socket-programming on the admin interface to send the correct bytes to do what you want is a bit out of the scope of this answer, so you can read more about that in the [official documentation](https://github.com/OpenTTD/OpenTTD/blob/master/docs/admin_network.md). There are also libraries available for java, javascript, PHP and python [linked on the wiki](https://wiki.openttd.org/en/Development/Server%20admin%20port#libraries_%2F_scripts). Assuming you know how to connect and communicate with the admin port:

The interesting packet type with which you can send commands like the above is (note that the openttd admin interface is little endian, opposite to usual network programming interfaces):

```
ADMIN_PACKET_ADMIN_RCON = 0x05 0x00
```

Append this packet identifier with the rcon command as a null-terminated C string (in our case: `string cmd = "set inflation false"`), or use one of the libraries to do the heavy lifting for you.

Also see the [wiki](https://wiki.openttd.org/Console) for more information about the console in general.